# Why doesn't it know how to build this task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task, rakefile

So I have the following task in rails running on jruby:

```
desc "Creates a new site with args: name, api_url (must be http(s)://api.something.com/v1/ - note the ending slash), api_key"
task :add_new_site, [:name, :api_url, :api_key] => :enviroment do | t, args |
  if !Site.find_by_site_name(args[:name])
    new_site = Site.new(site_name: args[:name], site_api_url: args[:api_url], site_api_key: args[:api_key])
    if new_site.save!
      puts "Created new Site: " + args[:name]
    end
  else
    puts "This site already exists."
  end
end
```

When I run it as such:

```
$ bin/rake add_new_site['sample', 'sample.com', 'addasdsd']
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'add_new_site[sample,'
```

You can see the error.

What am I doing wrong to receive this? I have other tasks that take one argument and they seem to work fine.

**Note:** yes this is in a `.rake` and not a `.rb` file

## Update One:

You can see from the below out put that I saw what was required of this task, and I tried it and it still failed:

```
$ bin/rake -T add_new_site ['sample', 'sample.com', 'addasdsd']
rake add_new_site[name,api_url,api_key]  # Creates a new site with args: name, api_url (must be http(s)://api.something.com/v1/ - note the ending slash), api_key

$ bin/rake add_new_site['sample','sample.com','addasdsd']
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'enviroment'

Tasks: TOP => add_new_site
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I seem to be getting a different error?

Comment: no, because if you do that then it runs add, sample and sample.com as three separate rake tasks.

Comment: you are absolutely right, sorry for wasting the time, I'll delete my comment :)

Comment: can you give the (relevant) output of `bin/rake -T` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `enviroment` instead of `environment`

That's why you are getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'enviroment'
```